# Kafka custom partition - consumers assignor with custom per partition user data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am implementing a custom  consumers to topics/partitions **assignor** in Kafka. To this end, I am overriding the `AbstractPartitionAssignor` abstract class which in turn implements the  `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` interface.

As part of the custom assignor, I want to send a single (float) information about **each partition of each topic that the consumers subscribe to**.

I am aware that I can send custom data to the assignor by overriding the default method
`ByteBuffer subscriptionUserData(Set<String> topics)` of the `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` interface.

However, the issue is that from the method signature above I can not get the list of partitions assigned to the underlined consumer for each of the topics that the consumer registers for.

On the other hand, I can see that the subscription class sent by each of the consumers to the group coordinator has a list of the owned partitions per consumer.

```
public static final class Subscription {
    private final List<String> topics;
    private final ByteBuffer userData;
    private final List<TopicPartition> ownedPartitions;
    private Optional<String> groupInstanceId;
    .....
```

Any hint on how I can send **custom per partition data** to the group coordinator through the method `ByteBuffer subscriptionUserData(Set<String> topics)`, or using any other way that relies only on kafka public APIs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the above issue, just use the `Assignor` callback function `onAssignment` as shown below

```
...
private List<TopicPartition> memberAssignment = null;
     @Override
        public void onAssignment(Assignment assignment, ConsumerGroupMetadata metadata) {
            memberAssignment = assignment.partitions();
            this.generation = metadata.generationId();
        }
```

and use `memberAssignment` inside the function subscriptionUserData (or any where in the Assignor class) to get the list of partitions currently assigned to each consumer.

```
public ByteBuffer subscriptionUserData(Set<String> topics)
```